# IF formula in Excel to calculate demurrage charges (Logistics)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I hope someone can help with with a question on IF formula in Excel. I am trying to calculate demmurage charges for logistic purposes, but I cannot get the formula to come out right. I will set the table below.

Driver has a 08:00 appointment and arrives on time. He has two free hours of load time prior to charging "wait" time. Driver is completed at 10:30, accumulating demurrage. I want the formula to tell me if the driver accrued detention charges.

IF(departure time) is greater than (appointment time)+2 hours "detention"

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**

```
=IF(ABS(A2-B2)<=2,"no","detention")
```

- Column A = Appointment Time
- Column B =  Departure Time

[image]

I tried and attached is the screenshot for your reference. Let me know if its helpful.

Comment: It did not work on my end. It just showed as FALSE. I am trying to get a picture of it to share, but it is not letting me upload the picture.

Comment: Share a screenshot of your data.

Comment: For whatever reason, It is not letting me add a picture or even a snip to the for you to see. Do you know a way for me to do that?

Comment: I have updated the answer. It should work now. Also, you can always update your question. You do not need to report your question as an answer. It can be confusing for other readers.